# how to edit my compare method

Tags: java, arrays, string, compare, filewriter

I want to compare contens of my two txt files and write the different words in other file3.txt file

I want to do compare method in this way to write another txt file.  Also I dont 
have an error for coding

I don't have a result. here is my code

Comment: *Where* doesn't it compile ? Pls show us your error messages

Comment: *"it doesnt compile"* => You should then have received a compilation error message, with a line number. Have you read it?

Comment: It **does** compile, checked it. There is only one unused var, `writer`.

Comment: but deneme3.txt I dont see the different words between deneme1.txt and deneme2.txt. how can I do for writing?

Comment: @Jes You said that it does not compile. Now you seem to say that it does compile, but does not do what you expect, which is quite different.

Comment: @assylias Im sorry for that but I said that I dont have an error for coding. yes It compiles but doesnt show the different words I think write part is missing

Comment: but I cant see my mistake at all

Comment: Are you sure those file paths are correct ?

Comment: @Jes Have you tried debugging your program, for example, by printing the size of `out` before writing it to the file? If its size is 0, then the problem is where you generate `out`, if it is not, then your problem is in the `write` method.

Comment: Finally: you have this line `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("D:\\Denemeler\\deneme3.txt"));` in the `compare` method AND in the `write` method: remove it from the `compare` method and it might solve your problem.

Comment: @SoboLAN Yes the files are correct

Comment: @assytlias I remove it, but it doesnt.

Comment: It is also not clear what you wanted to achieve. In the ques description you say you want to print different words but in the code you seem to be doing it the other way. You can use Collection retainAll/removeAll to achieve whatever you want http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)

Answer (score 3):

I just ran your program with the following files and could not reproduce your problem.

**deneme1**

```
abc
def
ghi
```

**deneme2**

```
abc
ghi
klm
```

And **deneme3** was created with the following content:

```
abc
ghi
```

**EDIT**

It seems you want the opposite behaviour. Some of your methods are unnecessarily complicated and could be made much shorter by using the right tools of the standard JDK. See below an example of a simplified implementation (that only keeps the words that are not in common between the 2 files) - **this example is case sensitive**:

```
public class TextAreaSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //readAllLines does what you do in readFileAsList
        List<String> strings1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:/temp/deneme1.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
        List<String> strings2 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\temp\\deneme2.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
        Set<String> notInCommon = getNotInCommon(strings1, strings2);
        write(notInCommon, "C:\\temp\\deneme3.txt");
    }

    private static void write(Collection<String> out, String fname) throws IOException {
        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("C:\\temp\\deneme3.txt"));
        for (String s : out) {
            writer.write(s + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();
    }

    private static Set<String> getNotInCommon(List<String> strings1, List<String> strings2) {
        //Sets are great to get unique lists and check commonality
        Set<String> onlyInFile1 = new HashSet<String>(strings1);
        onlyInFile1.removeAll(strings2); //remove strings in s1 AND s2
        Set<String> onlyInFile2 = new HashSet<String>(strings2);
        onlyInFile2.removeAll(strings1); //remove strings in s1 AND s2
        Set<String> notInCommon = new HashSet<>();
        notInCommon.addAll(onlyInFile1);
        notInCommon.addAll(onlyInFile2);

        return notInCommon;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's actually exactly the opposite of what he wants. ^^ Maybe that is his problem? But then, the question is very poorly formulated... ;)

Comment: @brimborium To be honest, I still don't know what the problem is or what he expects... But you might be right!

Comment: Well, he states that he wants the *different* words in file3, you have the words in file3 that occur in both files. But I think he should clarify this before we start doing anything. ;)

Comment: @brimborium He says one thing and then his code clearly does the opposite. The code is correct to the last letter, however, and works exactly as posted. So clearly there's room for different interpretations. He also said his code doesn't compile, so maybe trust code over words?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik **Never trust code**! :P Although in this case, maybe we shouldn't trust words either and just wait until more words/code comes in. ^^

Comment: @brimborium From my SO experience, the chances that we'll get any more words from OP are diminishing by the minute and are right now at about 10% :)

Comment: btw, @assylias: Very nice edit. In don't think that you have to create three `Set` though. `onlyInFile2.addAll(onlyInFile2); return onlyInFile2;` would suffice and would not loose in readability I think.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I bow to your experience but keep my newcomer naivity. ^^

Answer (score 3):

I have simplified and corrected your code into this:

```
public class TextAreaSample
{
  public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException {
    compare(readFileAsList("deneme1.txt"),
            readFileAsList("deneme2.txt"));
  }

  private static void compare(List<String> strings1, List<String> strings2)
  throws IOException
  {
    final Collator c = Collator.getInstance();
    c.setStrength(Collator.PRIMARY);
    final SortedSet<String>
      union = new TreeSet<String>(c),
      intersection = new TreeSet<String>(c);
    union.addAll(strings1);
    union.addAll(strings2);
    intersection.addAll(strings1);
    intersection.retainAll(strings2);
    union.removeAll(intersection);
    write(union, "deneme3.txt");
  }

  private static void write(Collection<String> out, String fname) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File(fname));
    try { for (String s : out) writer.write(s + "\n"); }
    finally { writer.close(); }
  }

  private static List<String> readFileAsList(String name) throws IOException {
    final List<String> ret = new ArrayList<String>();
    final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(name));
    try {
      String strLine;
      while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) ret.add(strLine);
      return ret;
    } finally { br.close(); }
  }
}
```

I have deneme1.txt:

```
plane
horoscope
microscope
```

deneme2.txt:

```
phone
mobile
plane
```

Output in deneme3.txt:

```
horoscope
microscope
mobile
phone
```

Comment: Your sample file is much more creative (in a geeky way admittedly) than mine ;-)

Comment: @assylias :) I actually saw your sample and thought it would aid readability if real words were used.

Comment: Shame on me - my version is a lot worse (see - I told you I'm not a professional!)

Comment: @assylias Heh heh, I'm actually cheating a bit, I learned this here at SO! Mind that the chief problem with your version is not ignoring case.

Comment: You are right - I had not noticed it was part of the original implementation. This Collator thingy is great (and I did not know about it) - thanks for sharing. You already had my +1 and I can't +2 ;-)

Comment: but your codes shows the smilar words BUT I want to find the different words?????

Comment: My code does exactly what your posted code does, Jes. So finally we learn, you DO want different words. This is a very simple change indeed.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik the code doesn't write deneme3.txt also I want to seem to be different words. there is plane in two txt. files

Comment: Jes. 1. **The exact code you posted writes the file** as confirmed by @assylias. 2. **My code writes the file** as confirmed by me. You claim **neither writes the file**. I really don't know how to help you with that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Still here? ;-)

Comment: @assylias I'm starting to struggle :)

Comment: @Marko Topolnik Im sorry for that it compiles thankyou  for your help :) last thing :( does it write word "plane" there is plane in both files:)

Comment: I see your point, you don't want all unique words, but only the different words. Fixed.

Comment: does it change the algorithm anyway ? there is plane in two txt files :s I dont want to see it in the deneme3.txt either

Comment: I don't see why you have to ask this. Run it and see. I did, of course, before posting.

Comment: I asked because I will show two txt. files JTextArea I want to seem to be bold different words

Comment: I think about like winmerge program so Im asking

Comment: You asked "does it change the algorithm anyway?". I replied "I don't see why you have to ask this."

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is don't try to solve everything in one shot.
You can simplify your compare method by using one liner
`strings1.retainAll(strings2)`

See this for more info
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#retainAll(java.util.Collection)

And print the contents of the strings1 and see if it is okay then solve that file writing part.

Comment: It is also not clear what you wanted to achieve. In the ques description you say you want to print different words but in the code you seem to be doing it the other way. You can use retainAll/removeAll to achieve whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the third file `deneme3.txt` twice without closing it in between. I guess the second time (in `write()`) an exception will be thrown, so there will be no write. Remove the first occurence of `FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("D:\\Denemeler\\deneme3.txt"));` (the one in `compare()`) and you should be fine.

Answer (score -2):

I think you have to flush() your writer before closing it.

```
private static void write(ArrayList<String> out, String fname) throws IOException {
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(new File("D:\\Denemeler\\deneme3.txt"));
    for (int i = 0; i < out.size(); i++) {
        writer.write(out.get(i) + "\n");
    }
    // Flush the writer before closing it.
    writer.flush();

    writer.close();
}
```

Comment: No, [`close` will **always** `flush`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close()).

Comment: From `Writer#close()` doc: [Close the stream, flushing it first.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#close())

Comment: Shame on me - looked it up it the sources, but i guess the native implementation does just that. Looking in the documentation helps. I stand corrected.