# Simple diff algorithm like winmerge.exe

Tags: java, swing, applet, project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to edit my compare method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11792534/how-to-edit-my-compare-method)

Comment: what is the output that you get? Describe your output?

Comment: only I took my contents of my two text files in two areas, on the screen.

Comment: I think you'll find winmerge isn't as simple as it looks.

Comment: yes I found some diff algorithms like winmerge programme. But I want to do something easier. I wrote my code but it couldn't be :(

Comment: @trashgod   any advice for my question??

Comment: [Same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11727609/230513) as the first time you [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11727448/230513).

Answer (score 3):

`JTextArea` is only for simple text - you could set the `Font` on it, but it would change how the *whole* text looks like.

If you want to add styles to parts of text, consider using `JTextPane`, which is made for this very purpose. See a [short example](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/SimpleAttributeBoldItalic.htm) on how to do that.